# Can I check for duplicate labels before knitting the whole document using knitr?

Tags: r, knitr

I have a report made of several `Rmd` files (several layers of child documents).

I always end up doing a copy paste and forget to change the chunk names, it's annoying because the report takes minutes to knit before the error pops up.

I use the chunk names to debug, and in the end they're often the ones that make my code crash, there has to be a better way.

How can I check programmatically that everything's clear before attempting to knit ?

Comment: Couldnt you extract all chunk names with a regular expression and then search for duplicates? This assumes you use a specific style for chunk names that can be identified by regex.

Comment: Would this help https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/957?

Comment: Have you tried setting: `options(knitr.duplicate.label = 'allow')`?

Comment: @LAP that's what I was about to do, but I'm happy that I asked first ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there exists this option that allows you to keep duplicate chunk labels and still knit:

```
options(knitr.duplicate.label = 'allow')
```